# Checking If Key Exists In Object Oriented Programming

Tags: php, json, google-maps, object, geocoding

Data from a Google API query sometimes is missing (such as when an invalid address is entered) and when that happens, there is an ugly error of an unknown key. To try to avoid the ugly error, I wrapped the call into a conditional but can't seem to get it to work at all that way because my object oriented programming skills are non-existent. Below is what I have and some attempts that are remarked out so what am I doing wrong? I really care only if ***$dataset->results[0]*** is valid as anything after that will be if it is.

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$Address&key=$googlekey";

// Retrieve the URL contents
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$jsonResponse = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);    

$dataset = json_decode($jsonResponse);

if (isset($dataset->results[0])) :
//if (isset($dataset->results[0]->geometry->location)) :
//if (!empty($dataset)) :
//if (!empty($dataset) && json_last_error() === 0) :
    $insertedVal = 1;
    $latitude = $dataset->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitude = $dataset->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
    return "$latitude,$longitude";
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that Geocoding API web service also returns a status in the response. The status indicates if there is a valid item in the response or something went wrong and you don't have any result.

Have a look at the documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#StatusCodes and you will see that there are following possible statuses

- "OK"
- "ZERO_RESULTS"
- "OVER_DAILY_LIMIT"
- "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
- "REQUEST_DENIED"
- "INVALID_REQUEST"
- "UNKNOWN_ERROR"

So, before you try to access `$dataset->results[0]` first check the value of the `$dataset->status`. If it is "OK", you can safely get the results, otherwise process the error code correctly.

Code snippet might be

```
 $dataset = json_decode($jsonResponse);

 if ($dataset->status == "OK") {
     if (isset($dataset->results[0])) {
         $latitude = $dataset->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
         $longitude = $dataset->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
     }
 } elseif ($dataset->status == "ZERO_RESULTS") {
     //TODO: process zero results response 
 } elseif ($dataset->status == "OVER_DAILY_LIMIT" {
     //TODO: process over daily quota 
 } elseif ($dataset->status == "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" {
     //TODO: process over QPS quota  
 } elseif ($dataset->status == "REQUEST_DENIED" {
     //TODO: process request denied  
 } elseif ($dataset->status == "INVALID_REQUEST" {
     //TODO: process invalid request response  
 } elseif ($dataset->status == "UNKNOWN_ERROR" {
     //TODO: process unknown error response 
 }
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed to know and, while you didn't address the exact question, your example showed checking isset($dataset->results[0]) just as I was doing which confirmed that I was doing it correctly. Adding $dataset->status == "OK" was a bonus, as were the specific error portions. Although I already had written a function to output the errors, I wasn't sure how valid it was so you helped confirm that too.